# Canvas App: Picklist values are not showing in Android

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, picklist, canvas, android

I am trying to show master org webpage in to Child Org using Canvas App. There is a picklist field on my webpage bound with apex:inputField.

Now, the picklist field options are showing in desktop browsers, Salesforce1 web version, iOS Salesforce1 but are not showing in Android Salesforce1. I am unable to select any values and its a mandatory field.

```
<apex:form > 
    <div class="slds">
        <div class="slds-form--horizontal">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="selectSample1">Sample label?</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Object.Field__c}" required="true" styleClass="slds-select"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</apex:form>
```